# MySQL Cte Statement

Tags: mysql

I am attempting to run a CTE statement in MySQL, and I am getting an error on the line that holds the WITH.  This is my full syntax, what do I need to change so this query executes like I wish.

And this is the error that I receive:

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) AS numbers(number) ), cte_tally10' at line 7

```
SET @v_start_date = '20190101';
SET @v_number_of_months = 12;

WITH
cte_input_values AS (
    SELECT CAST(TIMESTAMPADD(MONTH, TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, 0, @v_start_date), 0) AS date) AS start_date
),
cte_tally10 AS (
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) AS numbers(number)
),
cte_tally100 AS (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) - 1 AS month_number
    FROM cte_tally10 c1
    CROSS JOIN cte_tally10 c2
),
cte_months_to_pull AS (
    SELECT TIMESTAMPADD(MONTH, t.month_number, start_date) AS month_to_pull
    FROM cte_tally100 t
    CROSS JOIN cte_input_values
    WHERE t.month_number BETWEEN 0 AND @v_number_of_months - 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT TIMESTAMPADD(MONTH, t.month_number, TIMESTAMPADD(YEAR, -1, start_date)) AS month_to_pull
    FROM cte_tally100 t
    CROSS JOIN cte_input_values
    WHERE t.month_number BETWEEN 0 AND @v_number_of_months - 1
)
SELECT 
    INSERT(DATE_FORMAT (month_to_pull, 7), 4, 4, '') AS month_year,
    IFNULL(YRS.SaleAmount, 0) AS total_sales
FROM cte_months_to_pull
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT TIMESTAMPADD(MONTH, TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, 0, SaleDate), 0) AS SaleMonth,
        SUM(SaleAmount) AS SaleAmount
    FROM CurrentYear
    CROSS JOIN cte_input_values
    WHERE SaleDate >= start_date AND 
        SaleDate < TIMESTAMPADD(MONTH, @v_number_of_months, start_date)
    GROUP BY TIMESTAMPADD(MONTH, TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, 0, SaleDate), 0)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT TIMESTAMPADD(MONTH, TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, 0, SaleDate), 0) AS SaleMonth,
        SUM(SaleAmount) AS SaleAmount
    FROM PrevYear
    CROSS JOIN cte_input_values
    WHERE SaleDate >= TIMESTAMPADD(YEAR, -1, start_date) AND
        SaleDate < TIMESTAMPADD(MONTH, @v_number_of_months, TIMESTAMPADD(YEAR, -1, start_date))
    GROUP BY TIMESTAMPADD(MONTH, TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, 0, SaleDate), 0)
) AS YRS ON SaleMonth = month_to_pull
ORDER BY MONTH(month_to_pull), YEAR(month_to_pull)
```

Comment: See the first example for [Recursive Common Table Expressions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html#common-table-expressions-recursive).

Comment: The first `SELECT` returns a `NULL` value  for `start_date`. Are all these invocations of `TIMESTAMPDIFF` and `TIMESTAMPADD` really necessary? Given @v_start_date value  '20199191' what should be returned for `start_date`?  Why not just `SELECT @v_start_date + INTERVAL 0 MONTH AS start_date` ?

Comment: @spencer7593 It's an attempt to `/* insure @start_date is the first day of the month */` according to [sql-server fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/959d8/4)

Comment: @PaulSpiegel: That SQL Server fiddle isn't referenced anywhere in the question...

Comment: @spencer7593 It's in a comment to my answer.

Comment: Here is a beginners post for CTE https://thecodeframework.com/introduction-to-mysql-cte/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL doesn't support inline table construction with `VALUES`. It's though [supported by MariaDB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/table-value-constructors/)

However - As I see, you only need it for `cte_tally100` to generate sequence numbers from 0 to 99. But there is a better way to achieve that. See the first example for [Recursive Common Table Expressions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html#common-table-expressions-recursive). The query would be:

```
with recursive cte_tally100 as (
  select 0 as month_number
  union all
  select month_number + 1
  from cte_tally100
  where month_number < 99
)
...
```

[db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gfzsRD4HhE5p3XD2cumEwD/0)

If you only need numbers from 0 to 11 - change the WHERE clause to

```
where month_number < 11
```

#### Update

To get 12 next and 12 previous months, you can use:

```
SET @start_date = '20190102';
SET @number_of_months = 12;

WITH RECURSIVE
cte_input_values AS (
    # insure @start_date is the first day of the month
    SELECT DATE_FORMAT(@start_date, '%Y-%m-01') AS start_date
),
cte_tally12 AS (
    SELECT 0 as month_number
    UNION ALL
    SELECT month_number + 1
    FROM cte_tally12
    WHERE month_number < @number_of_months - 1
),
cte_months_to_pull AS (
    SELECT start_date + INTERVAL t.month_number MONTH AS month_to_pull
    FROM cte_tally12 t
    CROSS JOIN cte_input_values
    WHERE t.month_number BETWEEN 0 AND @number_of_months - 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT start_date - INTERVAL 1 YEAR + INTERVAL t.month_number MONTH AS month_to_pull
    FROM cte_tally12 t
    CROSS JOIN cte_input_values
    WHERE t.month_number BETWEEN 0 AND @number_of_months - 1
)
SELECT *
FROM cte_months_to_pull
```

[db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/Jp78Xh7EPZF9a2h2tCPW8/0)

That can also be done with a single (recursive) CTE:

```
SET @start_date = '20190102';
SET @number_of_months = 12;

WITH RECURSIVE
cte_months_to_pull AS (
    # insure @start_date is the first day of the month
    SELECT DATE_FORMAT(@start_date, '%Y-%m-01')
         - INTERVAL @number_of_months MONTH AS month_to_pull
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT month_to_pull + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
    FROM cte_months_to_pull
    WHERE month_to_pull < @start_date + INTERVAL @number_of_months - 2 MONTH
)
SELECT *
FROM cte_months_to_pull
```

[db-fidle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2BXfpqmU9ZDRsEuxZnaegB/0)

Now you can use `cte_months_to_pull` for your LEFT JOIN.

Comment: Hi Paul, and thank you for your response.  What I am after is outputting monthly data for Jan - Dec for 2018 and 2019.  So the output is Jan 18, Jan 19, Feb 18, Feb 19 etc.  Now the months where no data exists I want to show 0.

Comment: @DougLove what is the format of `month_to_pull`? YYYYMM ?

Comment: here is a fiddle that shows the MS SQL syntax :) http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/959d8/4

Comment: How do I join in my current year and previous year tables to get the data I'm after? - the sample CTE's that you provided above do Jan - Dec 2018 than Jan - Dec 2019.  I need it to show Jan 18, Jan 19, Feb 18, Feb 19 - which is why I had the MS SQL the way I did.

Comment: See [DATE_FORMAT(date,format)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) - `DATE_FORMAT(month_to_pull, '%b %y')`

Comment: if I alter the  SELECT statement to read `SELECT date_format(month_to_pull, '%b %Y') As Month_Year` .... it is still pulling all of 2018 then 2019?

Comment: Does [this](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gNzNJP6QZrXsMTfMPDkS91/0) answer your question?

Comment: Yes, I have that formatting added in but when the results are displayed I need it to show Jan 18 Jan 19, Feb 18 Feb 19 etc.  The output I show is like this https://ibb.co/68LwNqq

Comment: That's about [ORDER BY clause](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nF2Z2Evrw4PDiJ6XCrsyb4/0)

Answer (score 2):

I could be mistaken, but I don't think MySQL supports that form of `VALUES`; typically you'd do something like

`SELECT * FROM (SELECT 0 AS number UNION ALL SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 0) AS numbers`

Comment: we would need to use `UNION ALL` in place of `UNION` to avoid "collapsing" rows with duplicate values

Comment: Good catch. Corrected. I guess I am used to most of these use cases involving things like 0-9.

Comment: Changing the above like you suggest allows the syntax to run error free, but instead of having month and year output for MonthName it now shows NULL?

Comment: I don't see any result field named "MonthName" in your query; and after looking through it, I am wondering about DATE_FORMAT(month_to_pull, **7**). The second argument for [DATE_FORMAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) should not be an integer.

Comment: Sorry, it's month_year not monthName.  My mistake.  I'm not sure, I am not all familiar with MySQL syntax, but this works for MS SQL Server I'm just trying to convert it.

Comment: Yeah, not everything just copies over, [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) would be a good reference.

Comment: Thanks for the reference, I'm going to look through it.  I probably did NOT convert it correctly, in MS SQL it is this I was using `STUFF(CONVERT(varchar(12), month_to_pull, 7), 4, 4, '') AS month_year,`

Comment: Yeah, seeing INSERT outside of an INSERT query was kind of jarring to me, but I looked it up and apparently it's there.  MySQL's reference documentation is some of the best I've seen, so it is a good resource to lean on; I almost always ignore the initial google search results that oddly favor poorer quality third party references in favor of the official pages that usually appear 3rd or 4th in the results.